# Auto fill in content type

Tags: nodes, users

I have content type called services which has multiple filtered views.

What I need to do is when a new user registers his information, than I insert into that content type (services) one or more services he will provide. That means the user has the multiple check boxes on register page if he choose one services the specific view should display his information.

Is my structure right? Do I need to re-construct the data/types to get this result? Is it possible to proceed that way? and how? give me hint at least!

best

Comment: Could you explain whats a multiple filtered views in your content type is?